# Run-time error '1004' when using "=IF

Tags: vba, excel

Adding the following formula to cell using VBA fails and I can't work out why:

```
"=IF($02,(IF(NOT($N2),$P1+1,1)),0)"
```

I can change the line to anything else e.g "=A2/B2" and it runs fine.

Full code:

```
Sub FillDown() 

Dim strFormulas(1 To 2) As Variant 

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    LRow = .Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
    strFormulas(1) = "=IF($02,(IF(NOT($N2),$P1+1,1)),0)" 
    strFormulas(2) = "=A2/B2" 
   .Range("L2:T2").Formula = strFormulas
   .Range("L2:T" & LRow).FillDown 
End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: I formatted your code as `code`. Do you see the error now? :)

Comment: `$02`- `$O2` ---?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit it into your question. In this case you say you found the problem so why post your code?

Comment: change `strFormulas(1) = "=IF($02,(IF(NOT($N2),$P1+1,1)),0)"` to `strFormulas(1) = "=IF($O2,(IF(NOT($N2),$P1+1,1)),0)"` , and `.Range("L2:T2").Formula = strFormulas` to `.Range("L2:T2").Formula = strFormulas(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 strFormulas(1) = "=IF($O2,(IF(NOT($N2),$P1+1,1)),0)"
```

Instead of this:

```
 strFormulas(1) = "=IF($02,(IF(NOT($N2),$P1+1,1)),0)"
```

Comment: (took me a minute to see, by just to clarify OP had `02` ("zero two") instead of `O2` ("oh two"))